# What is the command for the solr 4.10.1 to be run in SOLRCLOUD mode through java code

Tags: java, solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have Solr 4.10.1 version installed on my machine. I have normally run the solr using the following command

> java -jar start.jar --OPTIONS=start

Actually Now In my application data is continuously increasing so one single collection taking too much time to load data. So I am implementing SOLR CLOUD for the same to split the data into different shards. For that using the commands given below worked for me to manual create shard

> $ bin/solr -e cloud

But I want to start SOLR CLOUD through passing parameters to start.jar command as if I start the normal solr wihtout cloud, and also I want to create shards automatically by passing the number of shards in the parameter list to start.jar.

Please me help out of the problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you planning on starting the Solr instance on each node in your cluster? Are you using an external Zookeeper ensemble? Have you gone through the standard SolrCloud setup on the wikis? In general, you put Solr in cloud mode by giving it information about its zookeepers, but exactly how that happens depends on how you're running Solr. I'd suggest reevaluating how you plan to deploy this to multiple servers (in general, it might be more useful to maintain Solr by itself, and just create a new collection when you need one through the Collection API in your Solr cluster).

Comment: @MatsLindh : Thanks for your reply. Actually i am trying to run solr in SOLR CLOUD mode using embedded zookeeper in solr. I have successfully run solr in SOLR CLOUD mode using "bin/solr -e cloud" command. But I have to run this same through java code using embedded zookeeper. I am missing some command to run the same. Please help me out of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing some java code as a custom start script that should directly invoke solr without using the command line or do you just want to invoke solr through the command line from your code?

Comment: @BinoyDalal : Thanks for your reply. I want to invoke solr in SOLR CLOUD mode through the command line from my code. Actually through my code i am just passing parameters to start.jar jar file like "java -jar start.jar --OPTIONS=start".. Through this command solr is started in normal mode. I want to start it to SOLR CLOUD mode. Please help me out of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer...append the parameters and you should be on your way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java -DzkClientTimeout=15000 -DzkRun=localhost:2181 -jar start.jar` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Binoy. Using above trick helped me a lot to run the solr in SOLR CLOUD mode.